# Virus scanning firebase storage files

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering whether it is cost effective to scan files uploaded to firebase storage using the firebase functions cloud storage finalize trigger and the node-clamAv package. I would have to read the file in and If any hit occurs just delete the file from storage.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-clamav OR https://www.npmjs.com/package/clamscan

I have read the doc about setting up a malware scanner... https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automating-malware-scanning-for-documents-uploaded-to-cloud-storage#gcp-console
But I would like to try and keep it all in one project.

How much would it cost to run each of the above methods and if one is more expensive, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The costs in GCP are mentioned in your doc: [Automating malware scanning for documents uploaded to Cloud Storage: costs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automating-malware-scanning-for-documents-uploaded-to-cloud-storage#costs):

- Cloud Storage
- App Engine flexible environment
- Cloud Functions

You can calculate an estimated with the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

1. You can select Google Cloud Storage Standard class, and the Amount of storage. The operation class are divived basically in [Operations A and B](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing). Class A (mostrly inserts), Class B (mostly gets), and free. Billing rates are per 10,000 operations.
2. In App Engine be sure to select Flex with the desired characteristics: Cores, Memory and Persistent disk, as well as the APIs and Services, in this case to Cloud Storage.
3. On the Cloud Functions you can select the Execution time per function in ms, Nework Bandwith and Invocations per month.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=963a7324-5970-4529-84a1-c382b338cdcc) is a quick sample of that .

Comment: I followed the tutorial in the link provided.
I have the malware-service running, it works.
But I have no idea how to make it to notify the final user of my app the status/result of the scanning.

I am thinking on access to the service log using a gcloud api.

What I would likle to see is a Cloud Run Service event I can subscribe to in order to get notified when the malware scan is finished and get the results.